# Error connecting zabbix with Mysql

Tags: debian, zabbix

I installed Zabbix v.2.4 from sources in Debian Jessie. I followed (step by step) this guide: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install
In the setup, when I have to configure the DB, I get this error:

```
The frontend does not match Zabbix database. Current database version (mandatory/optional): 2020000/2020001. Required mandatory version: 2040000. Contact your system administrator.
```

If I install from repos, the same happens. How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have forgotten to [initialise zabbix database](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/install/db_scripts).

Besides it is a mistake not to use official Debian packages from native repository. Zabbix-2.4 is available from "unstable". If you don't want to mix suites then it would be easier to re-build Zabbix packages rather than install from source. Package "zabbix-server-mysql" contains file `/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql/README.Debian` with instructions how to initialise database on first install...
Just remember avoid packages provided by Zabbix -- they are much worse than official Debian Zabbix packages from Debian repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted the solution in spanish, explaining the same. In addition, the zabbix-server-mysql need some dependences that cannot be solved in Debian Jessie, specifically with the libsnmp15, that is available only for the old stable releases. It is the main reason for using the source packages.

Comment: @verovan, you misunderstood my answer. Only incompetent .DEBs provided by Zabbix still depend on "libsnmp15". [Official Zabbix packages from Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/zabbix) do not have this problem. Never use packages from vendor if packages already available from Debian. See [ZBX-7996](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7996)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have been using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to do a new install of Zabbix 3.0  then you should first populate the database with the sql file provided in /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql/create.sql. After that it should work.

Comment: Please, read carefully the question: I was using Debian 8. And thanks for the answer, but this question has more than one year and the first answer is the right one.

Comment: @verovan. Yes I saw that but I just answered this question with the findings from my side because I was frustrated with the searches I did and nothing was working. So I thought of adding this answer too so that in future it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the database schema corresponds to Zabbix 2.2. Therefore, Zabbix 2.4 frontend says that existing database schema does not match the expected one. If you are upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4, then you can simply start the server and it will upgrade the database automatically. After that, you will be able to use the frontend. See [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/upgrade) on the general upgrade steps and a [blog post](http://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-2-2-features-part-1-automatic-database-upgrading/1956/) specifically on automatic database upgrade.

Comment: I am not upgrading. I installed from sources the 2.4 version.

Answer (score -1):

apt install mysql-server -y
systemctl start mysql.service
shell>mysql
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'mynewpassword';
mysql> quit;
sudo mysql_secure_installation
shell> mysql -uroot -p
mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
mysql> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by '';
mysql> quit;
shell> mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix < database/mysql/schema.sql

## stop here if you are creating database for Zabbix proxy

shell> mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix < database/mysql/images.sql
shell> mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix < database/mysql/data.sql

Comment: This does not even address the question

Comment: commands must be typed clear, preferably in curly bracket